# AWS API Gateway > Step Functions w/ XML payload

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, velocity, aws-step-functions, api-gateway

I have an API Gateway configuration that integrates w/ a Step Function (StateMachine) backend.
The API gateway accepts an XML payload via HTTP POST and applies a Integration Request mapping template to Content-Type: application/xml payloads.

When the XML has been minified on the client side (payload(1)), prior to being posted against the API Gateway endpoint, the solution works as expected.
However when the XML is not minified client side (payload(2)) the payload never reaches the StateMachine.

Below are sample payloads and the 3 mapping templates I have tried.

payload(1)

```
<XML><note><to>You</to><from>Me</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Testing</body></note></XML>
```

payload(2)

```
<XML>
    <note>
        <to>You</to>
        <from>Me</from>
        <heading>Reminder</heading>
        <body>Testing</body>
    </note>
</XML>
```

mappingtemplate(1)

```
{
  "input": "{\"body\": \"$input.body\"}",
  "stateMachineArn":"STATEMACHINE_ARN"
}
```

mappingtemplate(2)

```
{
  "input": "{\"body\": \"$input.path('$')\"}",
  "stateMachineArn":"STATEMACHINE_ARN"
}
```

mappingtemplate(3)

```
{
    "input": "{\"body\": \"$input.json('$')\"}",
    "stateMachineArn":"STATEMACHINE_ARN"
}
```

**Successful results:**

- payload(1) + mappingtemplate(1)
- payload(1) + mappingtemplate(2)

**Unsuccessful Results - Combinations that do not reach the statemachine**

- payload(1) + mappingtemplate(3)
- payload(2) + mappingtemplate(1)
- payload(2) + mappingtemplate(2)
- payload(2) + mappingtemplate(3)

Based on some research and discussion w/ AWS support I expect both payload(1)/payload(2) to reach the statemachine using mappingtemplate(3).
Doe have any insight into this?